# OpenSea Lazy Minting with Custom Contract

Tags: smartcontracts, nft, opensea

How can I get OpenSea to lazy mint with a custom contract I built?

In other words, how do I get OpenSea to communicate with my custom contract during the sale of a lazy minted token?

I don’t want the lazy minted token to show up on the OpenSea smart contract. I want it to live on my custom contract after purchase.

Comment: do you check [this](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/developer-tutorials) out?